# What law(s) prohibited Singaporeans from visiting the PRC, other communist countries, and the ROC? When were they repealed and why?

Tags: travel, singapore

In the past, for fear of communism, the Singapore government banned Singapore citizens below a certain age (I think 40 but I'm not sure) from visiting the PRC, North Korea, Cambodia, Laos, and Viet Nam.

From a [Reddit post](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14631369.2014.1001147) (passport said to be from the "early 80s"):

[image]

As you can see, the above passport page was amended to remove the ROC (Taiwan).

Later (I'm guessing c. 1980s), it was further amended to also remove also the PRC, North Korea, Cambodia, Laos, and Viet Nam.

Since 2017 the front passport pages look like this:

[image]

**Q1:** What were the laws prohibiting Singaporeans from visiting the PRC, North Korea, Cambodia, Laos, Viet Nam, and the ROC? When were they passed?

**Q2:** When were these laws repealed/amended and why?

**Q3:** Why were Singaporeans prohibited from visiting the ROC (Taiwan)?

---

Googling, it's surprisingly hard to find information on this.

Wong et al ([2015](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14631369.2014.1001147)):

> The government of Singapore decided that local residents below the age of 40 were not allowed to go to China, in order not to be influenced by communism.

In the magazine *Nautilus* ([2008](https://www.mpa.gov.sg/docs/mpalibraries/mpa-documents-files/comms-and-community/singapore-nautilus/singapore_nautilus_issue2.pdf?sfvrsn=6625bacf_2)), an interviewee says:

> At that stage [c. 1970], the Singaporean government did not allow locals under 55 to visit China

Comment: Googling is from the previous era. What does ChatGPT say?

Comment: @Greendrake: What Google said.

Comment: @Greendrake ChatGPT says [the lawyer who uses me has a fool for a research assistant](https://www.reuters.com/legal/new-york-lawyers-sanctioned-using-fake-chatgpt-cases-legal-brief-2023-06-22/).